# Why doesn't the reduce method work when calling an array within a function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why doesn't the reduce method work in the following code? It seems to work when I remove it from the sumAll function and reduce the array directly instead ([1,4].reduce...), but since arr is an array within the sumAll function, I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
function sumAll(arr) {
    arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
        return acc += curr;
    });

}

sumAll([1, 4]);
```

Comment: You have not set initial value. Place a `,0` after the closing `}`.  Also your not even returning the result..  e.g.  `return arr.reduce`

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? The function doesn't return the result.

Comment: @Keith the initial value is optional. If not specified, the first element is used as the initial value for the accumulator and the reduce starts with the second element.

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't return any value. You need a return statement at the beginning, like:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
        return acc + curr;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the result

```
function sumAll(arr) { 
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) { 
          return acc += curr; 
     });  
}
```